# CustomerPasswordHistory Table is a table where no unique customerId. customerId is duplicate how to join customer table unique id in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

> CustomerPasswordHistory Table

| Id | CustomerId | PasswordChangeBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1182 | ABC |
| 2 | 1182 | CDE |

> Customer Table

| Id | firstName | userIdentity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1182 | XYZ | 01231923123 |
| 2345 | asda | 12093109231 |

> Expected Outcome

| FirstName | PasswordchangeBy | userIdentity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | ABC | 01231923123 |
| 2345 | asda | 12093109231 |

How to find expected outcome using java native query

```
@Query(value = "select c.first_name, cph.password_change_by, c.user_identity  from wallet_db.customer.customer_password_history cph " +
        "inner join wallet_db.customer.customer c on cph.customer_id = c.id ", nativeQuery = true)
```

if run this query java throw unique value exception

Answer (score 0):

```
    import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CustomerPasswordHistoryResponse implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String passwordChangeBy;
    private String userIdentity;
}

@Query("select new com.sdfsdf.customer.domain.response.CustomerPasswordHistoryResponse(c.firstName, cph.passwordChangeBy, c.userIdentity) from CustomerPasswordHistory cph " +
        "inner join Customer c on cph.customerId = c.id ")
List<CustomerPasswordHistoryResponse> getAllHistory();
```